# Installing pywfdb python library from source

Tags: python, installation

I am trying to install the pywfdb library, these are the instructions, but I do not have any idea what they mean. I am on Mac OS X running an Enthought distribution of Python. I have downloaded the source, but from where it says "unpack" I am unsure of what to do.

1. Install  If you want to instal pywfdb from source you need to download WFDB library source code. Direct link to the latest version is http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb-no-docs.tar.gz  After downloading you have to:  Unpack WFDB library files, preferably to pywfdb directory.  Configure WFDB library with --without-netfiles switch, for example:  ./configure --without-netfiles --static --static_only --prefix=. --mandir=. Edit paths in setup.py to point to WFDB lib source and header files. If You have unpacked files to wfdbpy directory, the defaults should work.  execute python setup.py script:  python setup.py install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .gz extension means that the tar file was compressed using the gzip utility (or with the -z option in the original tar command)

Unpack means to run gunzip on the wfdb-no-docs.tar.gz file. This will now give you the wfdb-no-docs.tar file. You now run

```
tar xvf wfdb-no-docs.tar
```

cd into the directory created and follow the rest of the instructions.

You can also run tar directly using

```
tar -xzvf wfdb-no-docs.tar.gz
```

The z option tells tar that this is a gzip compressed file and it needs to be decompressed first (saving you the gunzip step).